# Is there any way to export/embed LibreOffice Base's forms into HTML pages?

Tags: php, html, forms, libreoffice, libreoffice-base

First: I know I am talking about two completely different worlds here.

I would like to **embed some LibreOffice Base's forms into my HTML pages, possibly keeping CRUD functions**.

I am requested to extend an existing web app, adding tons of already made LibreOffice Base's forms. 
The aesthetics should be kept (that means no easy table views). Some forms have 80-100 fields already set in a very nice and compact view that fits a screen.

Rewriting all by hand, and fine tuning for web, could be take months.

I tried some tools to ease the job, but all of them need a complete rewriting: PHP Generator, Simfatic, CRUD Admin Generator, fpmgonline, PHPRunner and some others.

**Is there any tool around to export these forms to html or to seamlessly embed them?**

The server is on a Linux machine.

Any hint is welcome.

PS: I am conscious I am trying to put together bananas and apples, but I also assume I am not the first one that had this need. If I am in the wrong group, please let me know.